# Xcode cannot compile if there are too many modifiers

Tags: swiftui

I have noticed that Xcode fails to compile with

The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

You can execute the below demo project to recreate the error. Once you uncomment confirmationDialog entries 11+ it fails to compile.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  confDialogTest
//
//  Created by Max on 13.06.22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingConf1 = false
    @State private var showingConf2 = false
    @State private var showingConf3 = false
    @State private var showingConf4 = false
    @State private var showingConf5 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(role: .destructive) {
            
            self.showingConf1.toggle()
        } label: {
            Label("Conf 1", systemImage: "trash.fill")
        }
        .padding()
        Button(role: .destructive) {
            
            self.showingConf2.toggle()
        } label: {
            Label("Conf 2", systemImage: "trash.fill")
        }
        .padding()
        Button(role: .destructive) {
            
            self.showingConf3.toggle()
        } label: {
            Label("Conf 3", systemImage: "trash.fill")
        }
        .padding()
        Button(role: .destructive) {
            
            self.showingConf4.toggle()
        } label: {
            Label("Conf 4", systemImage: "trash.fill")
        }
        .padding()
        
        Button(role: .destructive) {
            
            self.showingConf5.toggle()
        } label: {
            Label("Conf 5", systemImage: "trash.fill")
        }
//        .padding()
        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf1, titleVisibility: .visible) {
            Text("Conf")
        }
        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf2, titleVisibility: .visible) {
            Text("Conf")
        }
        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf3, titleVisibility: .visible) {
            Text("Conf")
        }
        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf4, titleVisibility: .visible) {
            Text("Conf")
        }
        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
            Text("Conf")
        }
        //next group is dialogs 6-10
        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
            Text("Conf")
        }
        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
            Text("Conf")
        }
        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
            Text("Conf")
        }
        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
            Text("Conf")
        }
        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
            Text("Conf")
        }
        //next group is dialogs 11-15
//        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
//            Text("Conf")
//        }
//        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
//            Text("Conf")
//        }
//        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
//            Text("Conf")
//        }
//        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
//            Text("Conf")
//        }
//        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
//            Text("Conf")
//        }
        //next group is dialogs 16-20
//        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
//            Text("Conf")
//        }
//        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
//            Text("Conf")
//        }
//        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
//            Text("Conf")
//        }
//        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
//            Text("Conf")
//        }
//        .confirmationDialog("Select location", isPresented: $showingConf5, titleVisibility: .visible) {
//            Text("Conf")
//        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Whiel it is easy to fix here if I just move some confirmationDialogs to another Button view, I have the same problem in another problem where I have to add many modifiers to a NavigationLink in a List View and there I cannot move it around ... :/

Any ideas what to do here?

Comment: Just don't do that, instead create a type with enum of all those cases and give one confirmationDialog depending on one state of that type and content depending on that state value.

Comment: Just tried that and it still returns me the same error

Comment: Show the code where you tried Asperi's suggestion in a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the root cause of the issue. In my other project with the same problem, I have a structure like

```
Zstack{
  List{
    ForEach(sectionArray){
      Section{
        ForEach(array){
          NavigationLink{
            RowView
          }
          .confirmationDialog()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so I was attaching the confirmationDialog to every single NavigationLink and that seems to have killed it. Once I rearranged it to

```
Zstack{
  List{
    ForEach(sectionArray){
      Section{
        ForEach(array){
          NavigationLink{
            RowView
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
.confirmationDialog()
```

the problem was gone.